# Uniformization of $\mathbb{CP}^2-\bigcup C_i$, where $C_i$ are Riemann surfaces intersecting generically

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds

Consider $X=\mathbb{CP}^2-\bigcup C_i$ where $C_i$ are Riemann surfaces intersecting generically.

How to compute the fundamental group of this space and what is the universal cover?

Comment: This case completely different from what happens in one dim. It's a theorem of Fulton that the fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}/\deg P$. So $\tilde X$ would be complement of a finite cyclic cover of the plane branched over the Riemann surface.

Comment: @DonuArapura Is there analogy of Fulton's theorem where we have several Riemann surfaces intersecting generically? ( I know it is a different question, but this is what actually interests me).

Comment: Yes, Fulton's theorem would apply to this case also. The fundamental group would be the direct sum $\oplus \mathbb{Z}/d_i$, where $d_i$ are degrees of the components.

Comment: @DonuArapura: wouldn't the fundamental group be $F \oplus \mathbb{Z}/D\mathbb{Z}$, where $F$ is free Abelian of rank $\#$components$-1$ and $D = \gcd\{d_i\}$?

Comment: @DonuArapura The fundamental group of the complement of three transverse lines is a free Abelian group of rank 2.  The Deligne - Fulton Theorem (= Zariski’s Conjecture) is that the complement of an at-worst-nodal plane curve has Abelian fundamental group.

Comment: If you suspect it's well known, maybe add the tag reference request?

Comment: OK, Marco and Jason are right. Leaving my comment from reference.

Comment: Isn't the result of @DonuArapura's first comment due to Zariski already? At any rate, that answers the question as currently stated. If the OP wants to ask something else, I suggest editing the question (since no answer has been posted yet — otherwise write out a new question).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: the history is a bit complicated. Zariski proved it based on Severi's theorem of the irreducibility the strata of the nodal variety (I think this is what's called), whose proof had a gap (later filled by Harris). In the meantime, Deligne and Fulton proved that Zariski's conjecture independently of Severi's "proof". (I've learnt this from Cogolludo's notes on braid monodromy, in Ann. Math. B. Pascal, 2011.)

Comment: @MarcoGolla Yes, I also learned the history this way (I believe from Joe Harris).

Answer (score 4):

(For the record, I am summarizing  the comments here.) Deligne and Fulton have shown that fundamental group of the complement of a nodal curve in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ is abelian. It follows easily that in the case of smooth curve $C$ of degree $d$, the fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}/d$. Therefore the universal cover in this case is the complement of the branch curve in the $d$-sheeted cyclic cover of the plane branched over $C$. See above comments for further historical remarks.

Comment: You can also do an irreducible nodal curve, and then you get the complement of a plumbing where you have a bunch of pairwise disjoint (-2)-curves, each intersecting the lift of the $C$ transversally twice, in a degree-$d$ hypersurface in $\mathbb{CP}^3$.